# Flutter change drawer header image at runtime

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, dart

I'm searching for a way to change the drawer header image when I switch the app theme from inside the app.

I have this code in my project to load an image to my drawer header.
But there has to be away to change the image just as it is possible to change the colors with `Theme.of(context).backgroundColor`

```
child: ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  children: <Widget>[
    UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
    accountName: const Text(_AccountName),
    accountEmail: const Text(_AccountEmail),
    currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
      child: Text(_AccountAbbr),
    ),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.blue,
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage('assets/md_drawer_header.jpg'),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether you change your theme using `BLoC` or `Provider` to Change your theme, you can provide your image from another source, as same as the way you provide your theme to `MaterialApp` widget.

Comment: I'm using `Provider` to change my theme. Do you have an example on how I can change the image ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this on my own.
I don't know if my solution was the best solution but it worked for me.

This is how I did it.

```
bool isDarkTheme = false;

class MdHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
      ...

      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: isDarkTheme
              ? AssetImage('assets/images/md_dh_dark.jpg')
              : AssetImage('assets/images/md_dh_light.jpg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  static headerImageIsDark(bool isDark) {
    isDarkTheme = isDark;
  }
}
```

Then in my class that was responsible for switching the theme at runtime I simply called the method like below.

```
MdHeader.headerImageIsDark(true);
```